# Is it possible, that intersection of regular language and context-free unambiguous language is inherently ambiguous?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Is it possible, that intersection of regular language and context-free unambiguous language is inherently ambiguous? If it is possible, give me any example please. Otherwise, I am looking for proof.

Answer (score 2):

No I think that is not possible, but you have to do a little work yourself.

If $L$ has a context-free grammar $G$, then the standard construction for a grammar for $L\cap R$ has nonterminals $[A,p,q]$ where $A$ is a nonterminal for $G$ and $p,q$ represents a path in an automaton for $R$, thus making guesses as what would be a fitting path for the derived terminal string. Now if the automaton for $R$ is deterministic and $G$ itself is unambiguous can there be several derivations for the same string?